# Sending slug in route using post in form

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, slug

I am trying to send {slug} in route:

```
Route::post('page-edit/{slug}', 'PageController@postSavePage');
```

in view I have:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'PageController@postSavePage')) !!}
```

in controller:

```
public function postSavePage($slug = null){
dd($slug);
}
```

but I have error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: page-edit/{slug}]. (View: /var/www/html/CMS/resources/views/admin/pages/page-edit.blade.php)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the slug to be [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), you have to add a question mark (?) to the parameter name in the `routes.php` file.

Like so:

```
Route::post('page-edit/{slug?}', 'PageController@postSavePage');
```

If you do not do this, you have to add the slug to the url of your form. Like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('PageController@postSavePage', 'slug'))) !!}
```

**Update:**

I suppose the page you are sending this request from is the same url as the one you are trying to post to. In this case the best thing to do would be to leave the action field of your form empty. This will make sure the form is submitted to the same url.

So you can just do this:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
```

Comment: my url is: `http://localhost:8000/page-edit/strona-2` so in slug should be 'strona-2' but if I use `{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('PageController@postSavePage', 'slug'))) !!}` and dump `dd($slug);` displayed: 'slug'

Comment: You have to replace `'slug'` with the value that has to be in the slug of your url.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really resolve this problem: the form submited to the same url

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing sending the `{slug}` parameter in the blade template as well :

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'PageController@postSavePage', $slug))) !!}
```

In your controller :

```
public function postSavePage($slug = null){
  // here's you can define $slug var, for example : 
  $slug = 3;
  return view('admin.pages.page-edit', compact('slug'));
}
```

Comment: When I use  `$slug` in Form I have error: `Undefined variable: slug (View: /var/www/html/CMS/resources/views/admin/pages/page-edit.blade.php)`

Comment: I've updated my answer, the name of the view I've wrote is maybe not correct, you have to check it. You have to pass the var that contains the slug to the view and then pass it through the Form. Hope this helps ;)